# Is there a way to load .h file for current .cpp file in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, macros, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2005

I have been developing in Visual Studio 2005 for ages, finally bit the bullet and moved to Visual Studio 2019. In VS2005 I have a macro that loads .h file for current .cpp file when I press Ctrl+H. I understand that macros are not supported in 2019 internally and that there are plugins that enable them, but they lack macro editor. Is there any way to achieve the same functionality I had in VS2019?

Comment: What do you mean by *loads .h file for current .cpp*?  Does it open the file so you can view it?  What happens if there is more then one header file?  You can right click on an include and select go to document (F12 is a shorcut) and it opens the header file for viewing.

Comment: @NathanOliver For example I am editing code.cpp and want to load code.h with a single key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No macro nor plugin is needed.  Just rightclick the editing pane within Visual Studio 2019 (while editing your `.cpp` source file), and select `Toggle Header/Code File` from the popup menu

Comment: Perfect! This is what I needed, thanks a lot.